# How To Optimize This Regular Expression Pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a bunch of patterns that I need to find in string, and they are as follows:

```
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="reference scale"/>
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="time"/>
<dyn type="page" property="name"/>
<dyn type="page" property="number"/>
<dyn type="page" property="index"/>
<dyn type="page" property="count"/>
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="<Field Name>" domainlookup="true"/>
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="<Field Name>" />
```

Example Usage:

```
Page <dyn type="page" property="index"/> of <dyn type="page" property="count"/>
```

which would result in

```
Page 1 of 15
```

I planned on using the regex of:

```
<dyn[^>]*/>
```

This would give:

```
regex = re.compile("<dyn[^>]*/>")
string = """Page <dyn type="page" property="index"/> of <dyn type="page" property="count"/>"""
r = regex.search(string)
print regex.findall(string)
[u'<dyn type="page" property="index"/>', u'<dyn type="page" property="count"/>']
```

but I don't know if it the best pattern to use (I'm convinced there is a better way).  This will find all patterns with the  pattern, but not the properties inside the tags.  Is there a way to write the regex in way that I can push the values to a dictionary object with all the values inside the <> as keys and the values after the = sign?

I just think there is a better way to do this, and since I'm not a wiz bang as regex, I figure I'd ask the community.

Thank you

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I'd like a Key/Value pair of the values inside the brackets.  Example: {'type':'page', 'property':'index'}, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\S+)="([^"]+)"
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/42

Make `group 1` as key and `group 2` as value.

Comment: this is very close to what I need, I find if you use the expression as a sentence, I get odd results.  See: https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/1 .  The results show extra text on the left side of the key, is there a way to eliminate that?

Comment: Awesome job! This does exactly what I'm looking for, I knew there was a better way!  Thank you for all your help!  I shall use this pattern: (\S+)="([^"]+)"

Answer (score 2):

Use an *XML parser*, like built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<root>
    <dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="reference scale"/>
    <dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="time"/>
    <dyn type="page" property="name"/>
    <dyn type="page" property="number"/>
    <dyn type="page" property="index">1</dyn>
    <dyn type="page" property="count">15</dyn>
    <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="Field Name" domainlookup="true"/>
    <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="Field Name" />
</root>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
index = root.findtext('.//dyn[@property="index"]')
count = root.findtext('.//dyn[@property="count"]')

print "%s of %s" % (index, count)
```

Prints `1 of 15`.

Note that the example is artificial since I'm not sure what your real XML input is. The idea, though, stays the same - an XML parser.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I don't think this gets to my point.  The tag formats are presented like this in any given string.  So something like "I walked to my house to make <dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="TEAFIELD"/> tea.  It was tasty".  So since it not pure XML, I don't think this will work?  Am I wrong here?

Comment: @josh1234 you are right, `xml.etree.ElementTree` would not extract the XML part from the text.

Answer (score 0):

Cracking XML or HTML with regular expressions can be an exercise in futility. Pyparsing includes an expression-builder helper method, makeHTMLTags, that will make very real-world tolerant parsers and will generate dict-like return values.

```
from pyparsing import *

dynTag,endDyn = makeHTMLTags("dyn")


sample = """
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="reference scale"/>
<dyn type="dataFrame" name="Main Map" property="time"/>
<dyn type="page" property="name"/>
<dyn type="page" property="number"/>
<dyn type="page" property="index"/>
<dyn type="page" property="count"/>
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="<Field Name>" domainlookup="true"/>
<dyn type="page" property="attribute" field="<Field Name>" />
"""

import pprint
for dyn in dynTag.searchString(sample):
    pprint.pprint(dyn.asDict())
    if "domainlookup" in dyn:
        print "domainlookup =",dyn.domainlookup
    print
```

Parsing your sample gives:

```
{'empty': True,
 'name': 'Main Map',
 'property': 'reference scale',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'dataFrame'], {}), (['name', 'Main Map'], {}), (['property', 'reference scale'], {}), True], {'type': [('dataFrame', 1)], 'property': [('reference scale', 3)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'name': [('Main Map', 2)], 'empty': [(True, 4)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'dataFrame'}

{'empty': True,
 'name': 'Main Map',
 'property': 'time',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'dataFrame'], {}), (['name', 'Main Map'], {}), (['property', 'time'], {}), True], {'type': [('dataFrame', 1)], 'property': [('time', 3)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'name': [('Main Map', 2)], 'empty': [(True, 4)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'dataFrame'}

{'empty': True,
 'property': 'name',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'name'], {}), True], {'type': [('page', 1)], 'property': [('name', 2)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'empty': [(True, 3)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}

{'empty': True,
 'property': 'number',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'number'], {}), True], {'type': [('page', 1)], 'property': [('number', 2)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'empty': [(True, 3)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}

{'empty': True,
 'property': 'index',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'index'], {}), True], {'type': [('page', 1)], 'property': [('index', 2)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'empty': [(True, 3)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}

{'empty': True,
 'property': 'count',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'count'], {}), True], {'type': [('page', 1)], 'property': [('count', 2)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'empty': [(True, 3)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}

{'domainlookup': 'true',
 'empty': True,
 'field': '<Field Name>',
 'property': 'attribute',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'attribute'], {}), (['field', '<Field Name>'], {}), (['domainlookup', 'true'], {}), True], {'field': [('<Field Name>', 3)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'domainlookup': [('true', 4)], 'property': [('attribute', 2)], 'type': [('page', 1)], 'empty': [(True, 5)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}
domainlookup = true

{'empty': True,
 'field': '<Field Name>',
 'property': 'attribute',
 'startDyn': (['dyn', (['type', 'page'], {}), (['property', 'attribute'], {}), (['field', '<Field Name>'], {}), True], {'field': [('<Field Name>', 3)], 'property': [('attribute', 2)], 'tag': [('dyn', 0)], 'empty': [(True, 4)], 'type': [('page', 1)]}),
 'tag': 'dyn',
 'type': 'page'}
```

Note that the resulting ParseResults structures will let you access the parsed attributes like object attributes (`dyn.domainlookup`) or dict keys (`dyn["domainlookup"]`).

Comment: The <dyn.../> are all the valid patterns I'm looking now, not the way the data is presented.

Comment: @josh1234 - what does that mean? Looking at your answer to alecxe, I think pyparsing may still be a good choice. Are you saying that you just want to pick out the `<dyn.../>` tags for now? You can use pyparsing's `originalTextFor` method to give you that, just use `originalTextFor(dynTag)` and you will get the matched XML text. But the next thing you will do is process the XML to get the fields and properties; the answer I've posted already takes that additional step. Also, pyparsing includes a `transformString` method that will do inplace sub of these XML strings with replacement values.